# How to sort 3d numpy masked array on time axis at each grid i.e at specific latitude and longitude for climate dataset

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a NetCDF file of Climate dataset having 3D structure with a shape of 20 * 445 * 445 as (time, latitude, longitude)

I have read it as `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray` using `netCDF4` library

I want to sort this `NumPy 3D-array` data on the `time axis` at `each grid` i.e.

at any specific grid `(latitude,longitude)` the value should be in either ascending or descending order

I have tried the [numpy.argsort function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) but the range of values at any grid/pixel exceeds the original value of dataset, so its not working i.e. the original dataset has values between 7 to 16, but after sorting, the values in dataset ranges from 1 to 19.

[the code is available at the Google Collab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I8TEchsctDv0839ifjWJLuswyhsCkpkN/view?usp=sharing), and [the NetCDF is available here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abhilashsinghimd/AASD_Geojson/main/3D_NC_to_Sort_along_time_axis.nc)

```
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
import sys,os,numpy as np,logging
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fileName = 'some_file'
data = Dataset(fileName, 'r')

temp_data = data.variables['Band1'][:,:,:]
```

Plots of original Dataset

```
for i in range(0,20):
    data_to_plot = temp_data[i]
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))
    ax.set_title('Layer '+ str(i))
    cax = ax.imshow(data_to_plot, cmap = plt.cm.Accent)
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(cax,
                        orientation='vertical',
                        fraction=0.045, 
                        pad=0.05)
    ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
```

```
sorted_temp_data = np.argsort(temp_data, axis=0)
```

Plots of Sorted Datasets

```
for i in range(0,20):
    data_to_plot = sorted_temp_data[i]
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))
    ax.set_title('Layer '+ str(i))
    cax = ax.imshow(data_to_plot, cmap = plt.cm.Accent)
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(cax,
                        orientation='vertical',
                        fraction=0.045, 
                        pad=0.05)
    
    ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `argsort` function doesnt return sorted array. It returns the index of sorted array. You can directly sort the array along the time axis (assuming time axis is the 0th axis) as follows:

```
np.sort(temp_data, axis=0)
```

If you want to use argsort the code should be like this:

```
idx = np.argsort(temp_data, axis=0)
sort_data = np.take_along_axis(temp_data, idx,axis=0)
```